# Can I use maven deploy to deploy multiple jars using maven?

Tags: maven

I am wondering if I can deploy multiple jars using maven deploy plugin?

Comment: Explain a bit more. It's not clear what your case is. Is it multiple projects you wanted to deploy all in one go or a case where you wanted to bundle the same project in different packaging (jar, war, zip,..) or it's one project and you want to include/exclude dependecies.

Comment: I think he means to say if we are having a set of external jars how to install them all at once using some maven command

Answer (score 2):

In case if 2 or more JARs should be deployed from one module use assembly:single goal of maven-assembly-plugin with the attach set to true:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Have all your projects whose JAR you wanted to deploy, as modules of a parent project and then when you deploy the parent project all the sub-projects JARs will be deployed.

See a tutorial here: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Link is invalid now.

Comment: @AmitKumar fixed the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As Nishant commented it, there is 2 cases.

**A project with its dependencies**

Lets say you have a master project, like a framework, which produces a bundle of jars. As it is a big project, it should be splitted into many little project. But there is one master project that drive all others. In a nutshell, it is a multi maven project

```
+-main-project/
+--src/
| +-- ...
+--pom.xml
|
+--submodule1
| +--src/
| +--pom.xml
+--submodule1
| +--src/
\ +--pom.xml
```

This will produce at least 2 jar (submodule1.jar and submodule2.jar)

Multimodule projects are intended to deal that kind of relations. A mvn deploy ill deploy all jars.

**A simple project that produce N jars**

Consider you have a project with multiple sources

```
+-main-project/
+--src/
| +--main/
| | +--java-core/
| | |--+/ClassA.java
| | +--java-entities/
| | |--+/ClassE.java
| | +--java-interfaces/
| | |--+/IClass.java
+--pom.xml
```

This would produce 3 jars (core, entities, interfaces). This would never be setted up !
The rule is 1 pom --> 1 artifact (2 in special cases, like resources, zip, ejb-client...)

So, mvn deploy won't be able to put more than 1 jar in distant repo. If you find a workaround (with some plugins), it's really a bad idea. Maven is not intended for that. But, don't worry, you just have to split your project to be in case one.

I hope it's clear enough, because your first message not really accurate :)

Comment: 1 pom - 1 jar good default rule, but there are reasonable exclusions when need to package and deploy jar-with-dependencies to easy run by `java -jar <jar file name>` or need to install test-jar with some test stubs or utilities to reuse in other modules etc... more general rule: all additional attached jars should have set unique classifier (file name suffix)

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk Totally agree with you ! +1